# UIAlertController triggers warning on iPad

Tags: ios, swift3, uialertcontroller

I have one question about adding a UIAlertController within my UIView and to prevent the app from crashing on iPads, I'm attaching it to a UIBarButtonItem. Now every first time when the alert is dismissed, I'm getting a warning:

[Warning] <_UIPopoverBackgroundVisualEffectView 0x7fbfee560c20> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.

I know this question was asked a couple of times before, but none of the answers seems to solve the problem in current versions of iOS.

I tried to turn off animation as this seems to help, but I'm not able to disable animation if any button is tabbed. How can I prevent the animation of the UIAlertController is dismissed?

My code:

```
    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    if let popoverPresentationController = optionMenu.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = button
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel"), style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

    let editAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Edit", comment: "Edit"), style: .default, handler: {
        (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editBirthday", sender: self)
    })
    optionMenu.addAction(editAction)

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Delete", comment: "Delete"), style: .destructive, handler: {
        (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            context.delete(self.birthday)
            appDelegate.saveContext()
        }
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    })
    optionMenu.addAction(deleteAction)

    present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I can call optionMenu.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) without any warning. But the action handler are executed after optionMenu was already dismissed. Overriding the dismiss function within my view isn't triggered at all.

Do I have to ignore the warning or is there anything I can add to prevent the animation?